# AjaxControlToolkit: HtmlEditor Textarea not showing in Chrome/Safari

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit, html-editor

I am using the HtmlEditor Control included in the AjaxControlToolkit (patched version v62210 because I needed some of the included fixes).

Unfortunately the textarea in the Html Editor control is never displayed in Chrome and Safari (both latest version). It doesn't matter if there is text in it or not. 
It does work on the AjaxControlToolkit Sample page with both browsers though.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

fixed it with the following css definition:

```
#ctl00_CR_TabContainer_TabPanelDetails_tbText_ctl02_ctl00
{
    height: auto !important;
}
```

The selector is page specific but can be determined easily using Firebug.

Comment: A better way to reference the iframe in css is .ajax__htmleditor_editor_base iframe
{
    height: auto !important;
}

Answer (score 2):

Try to set this property of the editor:

```
InitialCleanUp = true
```

This should resolve chrome and IE9 postback issue also.

Answer (score 0):

just define height and width in chrome browser, so text area will appear. as example.

height="300" and width="500" in Editor property.

Comment: Hey, have you actually tried this because I have never been able to get it to work this way? If you have, I am curious what you did differently.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I know this is a year too late, but I had this same exact problem, and I fixed it by setting the height property from the code-behind. I wasn't able to use @simmonw 's answer because I am adding mine to the page dynamically and I had no way of knowing what the selector would be named. Anyways, hopefully this will help someone.